# how to call sidekiq worker every times with certain duration of time between calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

So I have a worker. I want him to start every 2 weeks to clean some data. How can I do this? I know about perform_in and perform_at but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduled, recurring jobs are not part of the core Sidekiq functionality. You can either upgrade to [Sidekiq Pro](http://sidekiq.org/products/pro), which includes support for scheduled jobs, or use an open-source scheduling plugin like [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler).

With the latter, to run your job every two weeks, you'd use a config like:

```
your_job_name_here:
  every: 2w
  class: YourWorker
  queue: default
  description: "Runs every two weeks"
```

Comment: where should I write this config?

Comment: @ВиталийПапроцький: first, [install the gem](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler#installation); then, follow the directions [here](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler#loading-the-schedule). Let me know if you run into trouble.